# encrypt password in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, encryption

I have a shell script which has a java command which has two variables --username and --password

```
java -cp "oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar" oracle.ucm.client.UploadTool --url="" --username="HCM_IMPL" --password="Welcome1" --primaryFile="/scratch/HRDataFile.zip" --dDocTitle="Department Load File" --dSecurityGroup="FAFusionImportExport" --dDocAccount="hcm/dataloader/import"
```

I dont want the password to go as free text in the shell script. Instead i want to encrypt it. Is there a way to do this ?

[Hide/encrypt password in bash file to stop accidentally seeing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318853/hide-encrypt-password-in-bash-file-to-stop-accidentally-seeing-it)

In this example password is being passed as parameter which is not the case with my script. Secondly i cannot download aesutil or passwd as I am using SSH Tectia.